# jQuery masonry issue

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-masonry

I'm having a bit of bother with my web page. I'm using the jquery plugin masonry and it works great however I'm having an issue which I can seem to fix.

Basically, I hide the div which the masonry is contained within when a button is clicked which works fine and when I click another button to bring it back it appears again. So that's all working fine BUT if I resize my browser before clicking to bring back the masonry, all of the masonry tiles are positioned one on top of the other in the top left corner. When I inspect with firebug the correct positioning is added to each div but it seems that css is ignoring these yet when I refresh the masonry moves each tile to where it should be...any idea on how I can fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it - I just called the masonry function again! :) Thanks anyways!